# How to use Sitecore Item Web Api and query for a Sitecore item with a particular value in the field?

Tags: sitecore-query

I am trying to query for a Sitecore item where a particular field has a particular value but am not successfull in doing so.

I am trying to do `http://sc8/-/item/v1/?query=/sitecore/content/Home/*[@Title=#Welcome to Sitecore#]`

The response I am getting is
 {
"statusCode": 400,
"error": {
"message": "Bad Sitecore query (/sitecore/content/Home/*[@Title)."
}
}

Can any one correct me please?

Comment: Try http://sc8/-/item/v1/?query=/sitecore/content/Home/*[@Title = 'Welcome to Sitecore']  this

Answer (score 6):

I believe the problem is the hash (#) signs instead of quotes (') around values.

This is a sample query from the Item Web API documentation:
`/sitecore/content/Home/*[@Title='Welcome to Sitecore']`

Documentation link (old, but I could not find any more recent):
https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf

Hash (#) signs are used to escape item names in the path and field names when they contain protected characters and words:
`/sitecore/content/Home/#our-products#/*[@#category-type#='something']`

See e.g. these links for more details on the query syntax:
https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-query-cheat-sheet
https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Using%20Sitecore%20Query/Sitecore%20Query%20Syntax.aspx